# Is this jdbc resource closed?

Tags: java, jdbc

Looking back over my code I find that I occasionaly have written:

```
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from main");
//snip
rs.close();
```

and sometimes I've written

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from main");
//snip
rs.close();
st.close();
```

In the second code segment, it's more obvious that the Statement is closed, but is it also closed in the first one? conn.createStatement() returns a statement object, but when it's instantiated like that I don't see any easy way to close it after I'm done. Should I just rewrite the various bits of code to use method #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Statement` will be automatically closed when it is garbage collected, but you need to explicitly close it if you want to free the resources as soon as you're done with them.

Note, however, that the reverse actually does work. That is, closing a `Statement` also closes the `ResultSet` associated with it.

Comment: Are you sure that all `Statement`s are closed when they are garbage collected? The Javadoc does not specify any behavior regarding that class's `finalize()` method.

Answer (score 2):

A good practice is to put the `rs.close()` and `st.close()` in your finally clause.

```
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

try {
   st = connection.createStatement(...);
   rs = st.executeQuery();
}
catch (JdbcErrorsExceptionsAndFoo exception) {
   // yadda yadda
}
finally {
    if (rs!= null) {
        rs.close();
    }
    if (st != null) {
        st.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Though not perfect, this is better than not using any `finally` block.

Comment: Oh, yeah, there's way better patterns to use.  But this gets the point across.

Comment: @Marvo, if you have better patterns, please feel free to add them as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

if statement contains a resultset, gc does not collect it. you can use the second method or use aspects or filters to auto close them.